# getting phone number of android device

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the phone number from android device using TelephonyManager.

what is READ_PHONE_STATE? I included it in the manifest file. but still it is throwing exception.

Manifest file,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="abc.sample"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:permission="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
    <activity android:name=".TrakkitActivityMain"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TermsOfServiceActivity" android:label="Terms Of Service"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".CategoryMainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ExpensesMainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".CategoryDefineActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ExpensesDefineActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".CategoryPieChartActivity"></activity><receiver android:name=".receivers.AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
    <activity android:name=".ChartDisplayViewActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".LandingPageActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SpeedOMeterViewActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".FeedbackActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".CategoryDeleteActivity"></activity>


</application>
```

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String phoneNo = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
```

it is returning empty phoneNo=""

Answer (score 2):

I think this snippet should work. At least it does at my phone.

```
private String getMyPhoneNumber(){
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
        mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)
            getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
    }

    private String getMy10DigitPhoneNumber(){
        String s = getMyPhoneNumber();
        return s.substring(2);
    }
```

Comment: Yes that's how it should work but the OP should test this carefully because I've read many comments about `getLine1Number()` which sometimes return with null value or with the phone number originally stored in SIM card. U know, a SIM card doesn't always stick with one particular phone number but depends on the Mobile Operator

Answer (score 1):

As far I as know, it's not possible to obtain phone number. The SDK provides the methods but it will return null most of the cases.

Comment: It is possible, but as you say in your comment under Roflcoptr's answer, it isn't always reliable.